# Create a var/val of singleton class in scala

Tags: scala, singleton

I have created a class as :

```
class Standalone(val str:String)
{
    Console println "Creating : "+this;
    override def toString()= " str : "+str;
}
object StandaloneFactory
{
    private val standalones= Map("red"-> new Standalone("Red"),"blue"-> new Standalone("Blue"),"green"-> new Standalone("green"));
    def getColor(color : String) = if(standalones.contains(color)) standalones(color) else null;
}
```

I know Object StandaloneFactory will have a single instance as StandaloneFactory. I just want to create a var/val of Standalonefactory so I tried to this :

```
object StandaloneMain
{
    def main(args:Array[String])
    {
        var stdFac:StandaloneFactory= StandaloneFactory;
        Console println stdFac;
        Console.println(StandaloneFactory.getColor("red")); 
    }
}
```

but this does not compile and give error as following :
**error: not found: type StandaloneFactory**

Now as I change

```
var stdFac:StandaloneFactory= StandaloneFactory;
```

to

```
var stdFac:StandaloneFactory.type= StandaloneFactory;
```

or

```
var stdFac= StandaloneFactory;
```

Code compiles and run successfully . **I think it is related with aliasing in scala**. I am not getting what is happening . Please help me to understand this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an object, `StandaloneFactory` is a *value*, not a type. It is the sole instance of some type whose name is not apparent to you, but is available as `StandaloneFactory.type`. The name of the type is generated, currently by adding a `$` to the object name -- in this case `StandaloneFactory$`. After compiling you will see such a classfile.

You asked for a reference explaining that `object StandaloneFactory` creates a value `StandaloneFactory` rather than a type by that name. Please see the bottom of [this page](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html) in the Scala language spec, where both a class and an object named `Point` are created, and it says

> the class definition defines the name Point in the type name space,
>   whereas the object definition defines a name in the term namespace.

The two namespaces are discussed [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html). The "type namespace" is used for symbols that refer to types, and the "term namespace" is used for symbols that refer to ***instances*** of types.

Just to be crystal clear here, when you say
`object StandaloneFactory`
you create a type (whose name is `StandaloneFactory$`, not `StandaloneFactory`) *and* a value `StandaloneFactory` (which points to the only instance of `StandaloneFactory$`). You might be surprised at first that value `StandaloneFactory` does not point to an instance of type `StandaloneFactory`, but if you know about companion objects and case classes you will realize that the companion object for a type is a completely different animal from the type; it has to have its *own* type.

Comment: will you please provide any reference or link explaining that  object classes  are created as `value`

Comment: I just want to clarify something.  You asked for a link explaining that *object classes* are created as values -- well, if by "object class" you mean the class underlying the object, that is *not* a value.  It's a type.  But the *object* (not "object class") is a value.